# CPU percentage and heavy multi-threading

Tags: linux

I am observing strange effects with the CPU percentage as shown in e.g. top or htop on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) for one special application. The application uses many threads (around 1000). Each thread has one computational task. About half of these tasks need to be computed once per "trigger" - the trigger is an external event received exactly every 100ms. The other threads are mostly sleeping (waiting for user interaction) and hence do not play a big role here. So to summarise: many threads are waking up basically simultaneously within a short period of time, doing there (relatively short) computation and going back to sleep again.

Since the machine running this application has 8 virtual CPUs (4 cores each 2 threads, it's an i7-3612QE), only 8 threads can really wake up at a time, so many threads will have to wait. Also some of these tasks have interdependencies, so they anyway have to wait, but I think as an approximation one can think of this application as a bunch of threads going to the runnable state at the same time every 100ms and each doing only a short computation (way below 1ms of CPU time each).

Now coming to the strange effect: If I look at the CPU percentage in "top", it shows something like 250%. As far as I know, top looks on the CPU time (user + system) the kernel accounts for this process, so 250% would mean the process uses 3 virtual CPUs on average. So far so good. Now, if I use taskset to force the entire process to use only a single virtual CPU, the CPU percentage drops to 80%. The application has internal accounting which tells me that still all data is being processed. So the application is doing the same amount of work, but it seemingly uses less CPU resources. How can that be? Can I really trust the kernel CPU time accounting, or is this an artefact of the measurement?

The CPU percentage also goes down, if I start other processes which take a lot of CPU, even if the do nothing ("while(true);") and are running at low priority (nice). If I launch 8 of these CPU-eating processes, the application reaches again 80%. With fewer CPU-eaters, I get gradually higher CPU%.

Not sure if this plays a role: I have used the profiler vtune, which tells me my application is actually quite inefficient (only about 1 IPC), mostly because it's memory bound. This does not change if I restrict the process to a single virtual CPU, so I assume the effect is not caused by a huge increase in efficiency when running everything on the same core (which would be strange anyway).

Comment: What is the ratio of system time / user time / wait time in multicore setup? in singlecore setup?

Comment: @gudok How do I find out the wait time for a process? /proc/pid/stat mentions only system and user time as far as I know... The ratio of system to user time stays roughly constant if I force the process on a single core compared to run it on all cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was essentially already answered by myself in the last paragraph: The process is memory bound. Hence not the CPU is the limited resource but the memory bandwidth. Allowing such process to run on multiple CPU cores in parallel will mainly have the effect that more CPU cores are waiting for data to arrive from RAM. This is counted as CPU load, since the CPU is executing the thread, but just quite slowly. All my other observations go along with this.